# Difference between selenium-support and selenium-java jars

Tags: selenium

I'm  confused about the use of the selenium-support jar file.

There is another achieve available called selenium-java.jar, which is selenium java binding.

Where I can use selenium-support jar?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a valid question

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven generally you want to have your project dependant only on selenium-java. selenium-support is one of the dependencies of that. Maven will resolve these dependencies for you.

If you are just using a plain project, then linking to selenium-standalone will contain all these in one package.

Additional information can be found in the [official documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Support:
Selenium is a set of different software tools each with a different approach to supporting browser automation. These tools are highly flexible, allowing many options for locating and manipulating elements within a browser, and one of its key features is the support for automating multiple browser platforms. This package contains .NET support utilites and classes that users may find useful in using Selenium WebDriver. These support classes are mainly intended to spark ideas of what is possible with Selenium WebDriver, and may not be entirely appropriate for production use.

Selenium Java Jars:
Selenium Standalone Server - is a java jar file which is used for starting selenium server which is as word say server, proxy to selenium grid for browsers you want to automate